# Why this code does not match?

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-studio

I currently doing simple custom webpart but this line of code will never works:

Hello.ascx.cs

```
if (strName == ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME)
{
    ManageError("group " + strName.Trim() + " and " + ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME+ " match");
}
else
{
    ManageError("group " + strName.Trim() + " and " + ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME+ " doesn't match");
}
```

already assigned

```
string strName = "MyName";
```

ManageError class

```
private void ManageError(string str)
{ lblError.Text = str; }
```

in my ConstantHelper

```
public class ConstantHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is where to store all info about Site List/Libraries
        /// </summary>
        public class List
        {
            public const string MYNAME= "MyName";
        }
    }
```

but the result always

> group MyName​​​ and MyName doesn't match

help me :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

== is like ReferenceEquals, use Equals instead:

```
if (object.Equals(strName, ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME))
```

or

```
if (strName.Equals(ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME))
```

See this article: stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792

Comment: yeah sorry about it, i forgot to put here.

Comment: Did tou tried `string strName = MyName.toString();`?

Comment: sorry again, i forgot to put "MyName". edited already

Comment: try `if (strName.Equals(ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME, StringComparison.Ordinal))`

Comment: Have you tried string trimming before comparison? Does it have to be case sensitive?

Comment: Tried the trimming before comparison, same result. Tried all caps and all small letters, same result.

Comment: `if (object.Equals(strName, ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME))` or `if (strName.Equals(ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME))`

Comment: See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same

Comment: Your code/the article works but in new webpart only not in my old one together with other functions. Maybe because of the nesting I made. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine! it produces the correct result on VS,

> group MyName​and MyName match

just copied and pasted code!

You need to put a break point on this line:

```
if (strName == ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME)
```

and step into the next line, then see why its a missmatch, hover over the two your comparing to see whats being outputted! I bet if you did the following would work:

```
string getStringName = ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME;
if (strName == getStringName)
```

or

```
if (strName == ConstantHelper.List.MYNAME.ToString())
```

that should work as your comparing string with string! maybe your compiler is getting confused??